# Samba stopped working... wrong interface?

Tags: networking, server, samba

After a few days, my samba installation stopped working: the processes are running, testparm is ok, but seemingly it can't connect to the local interface properly (?). I've scanned forums for hours, but no interface-related solution was up. this is what smbtree -d3 gives back:

```
Initialising global parameters
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
params.c:pm_process() - Processing configuration file "/etc/samba/smb.conf"
Processing section "[global]"
added interface lo ip=127.0.0.1 bcast=127.255.255.255 netmask=255.0.0.0
Enter pbserver's password: 
tdb(/var/cache/samba/gencache.tdb): tdb_open_ex: could not open file /var/cache/samba/gencache.tdb: Permission denied
name_resolve_bcast: Attempting broadcast lookup for name WORKGROUP<0x1d>
samba_tevent: EPOLL_CTL_DEL EBADF for fde[0x7fcd16f14e60] mpx_fde[(nil)] fd[7] - disabling
name_resolve_bcast: Attempting broadcast lookup for name WORKGROUP<0x1b>
samba_tevent: EPOLL_CTL_DEL EBADF for fde[0x7fcd16f14e60] mpx_fde[(nil)] fd[7] - disabling
name_resolve_bcast: Attempting broadcast lookup for name __MSBROWSE__<0x1>
samba_tevent: EPOLL_CTL_DEL EBADF for fde[0x7fcd16f14df0] mpx_fde[(nil)] fd[7] - disabling
```

My config's global:

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
netbios name = BorzServer
guest ok = yes
read only = no
security = user
wins support = yes
guest account = nobody
os level = 66
hosts allow = localhost, 192.168.
bind interfaces only = yes
preferred master = Yes
domain master = Yes
local master = yes
unix extensions = no
name resolve order =  bcast
interfaces = 127.0.0.1
```

If I delete "interfaces", smbtree gives back my other computer's shares (for any user). the original installation value was 127.0.0.0/8 eth0 but this gives back even more errors (can't find address for eth0)

Answer (score 0):

Try only to add interface name after `127.0.0.1` in your global config

```
interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0
```

Comment: As I said in the last paragraph, changing to this default value results in not even finding any network interface. specifically: 
(...) Processing section "[global]"
interpret_interface: using netmask value 8 from config file on interface lo added interface lo ip=127.0.0.1 bcast=127.255.255.255 netmask=255.0.0.0
interpret_string_addr_internal: getaddrinfo failed for name eth0 (flags 32) [Name or service not known]
interpret_interface: Can't find address for eth0